# how to hold datetime into a field in oracle?

Tags: oracle

will date datatype hold datetime? its not taking datetime.

i have to store datetime into a field in table, for that which datatype i have to use?

Thanks,
Srikanth

Comment: thank you for ur clarification........i will do accept answers from now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date field does hold date time but you'll need to use the to_date function

for example, if you're trying to insert 2009/01/04 09:00:00 you will use

```
insert into table_name
(date_field)
values
(to_date('2010/01/04 09:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss'));
```

Note the datetime mask used to tell the field what format the data is arriving in

Comment: is there any datatype which defaultly can hold datetime?